# Get List of SVN Tags from Urbancode Ubuild

Tags: svn, urbancode

I need to get the list of SVN Tags used for build in Ubuild.
I have a list of build numbers and the application names for which the tag name needs to obtained. This list is pretty huge.
Is there any pretty easy way of getting this list?